# Comparing elements of the $n^{\text{th}}$ sublist in a ragged list with the $n^{\text{th}}$ member of a sequence

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists that are not of the same length (for example, `{{6}, {14}, {6, 26, 30}}`), but I have to compare every element in the $n^{\text{th}}$ sublist with the corresponding $n^{\text{th}}$ odd number. So, 6 in the first sublist with 1 (first odd number), 14 in the second sublist with 3 (second odd number), 6 with 5 (third odd number), 26 with 5, 30 with 5, etc.

I tried to make another list with odd numbers, but I really don't know how to program the case when the comparison is with only one element in the sublist (e.g. sublists 1 and 2) and with multi-element sublists (e.g., 3rd sublist).

Comment: Your last few questions have made me curious: what is your *actual problem* that has you dealing with lists of lists with different lengths?

Answer (score 11):

[`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html) is your friend :) The part specification for each of the sublists is supplied as a second argument to the function being mapped. With this, you can construct your $n^{\text{th}}$ odd number to compare against. For example:

```
list = {{6}, {14}, {6, 26, 3}, {5, 10}};
MapIndexed[Thread[# > First@(2 #2 - 1)] &, list]
(* {{True}, {True}, {True, True, False}, {False, True}} *)
```

Replace `>` (`Greater`) with `<` (`Less`) or `==` (`Equal`) or any other comparison function as per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Something like :

```
data = {{6}, {14}, {6, 2, 30}};

odds = 2 # + 1 & /@ Range[0, Length[data] - 1];

MapThread[Thread[Greater[#1, #2]] &, {data, odds}]

(* {{True}, {True}, {True, False, True}} *)
```

If the condition is :

```
cond[x_, y_] := If[x > y, Pi y, 0]
```

then one needs to wrap it with `Unevaluated` :

```
MapThread[Thread[Unevaluated[cond[#1, #2]]] &, {data, odds}]

(* {{\[Pi]}, {3 \[Pi]}, {5 \[Pi], 0, 5 \[Pi]}} *)
```

Comment: I'd have done `odds = Range[1, 2 Length[data] - 1, 2]` myself...

Comment: And if I don't want Mathematica to write {True, True} but to calculate something with numbers that satisfy conditions?
For example: If True, Print[\pi*(2k+1)]?

Comment: @WayneGacy Just change the function `Greater` to what you need.

Comment: MapThread[Thread[If[#1 == 3.14*#2, Print[#1]]] &, {data, odds}]



{If[{6} == 3.14, Print[{6}]], If[{14} == 9.42, Print[{14}]], 
 If[{6, 2, 30} == 15.7, Print[{6, 2, 30}]]}



If I put that line in Mathematica, the output is like line above. I don't want to write that, only that sublist whose elements satisfy condition.

THANK you!

Comment: @WayneGacy Please see edit.